# How to speed up for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, distribution

```
rm(list=ls())
library(gld)
library(GLDEX)

find_likelihood = function(x){
  fit = fit.fkml(x,"ML",return.data=TRUE)
  params = fit$optim.results$par
  dens = dgl(x, c(params), param = "fmkl", inverse.eps = 1e-08, max.iterations = 500)
  dens[dens < 1e-12] = 1e-12
  value = -sum(log(dens))
  return(value)
}

loglik_com = NULL
min_value = NULL

  for(j in 1: 1000){
    x = rgl(100,c(2, 1, 1, 1), param="fkml")
    for (i in 2:(100 - 2)) {
      a = x[1:i]
      b = x[(i + 1):100]
      loglik_com[i] = find_likelihood(a) + find_likelihood(b)
    }
    min_value[j] = min(na.omit(loglik_com))
  }

min_value
```

In my above R function, I have 1000 iterations but it takes nearly 7 hours to get results. My question is, am I able to use apply() function to speed up the results? Or any other way that I can use to speed up my r function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the call to rgl do in the loop. It seems it is not necessary to do that inside the loop. Actually, the entire for j loop seems to do nothing in your example. Could be because you simplified your exampl, which is good, but in that case mention that in your question.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan, that rgl function allows to generate random sample in each iterations.

Answer (score -1):

You could try some sort of parallelisation, I see there is the Parallel package? Have not had any personal experience however. 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.6.2
https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html